# Is it necessary to explicitly flush the HDD on-disk write caches?

Tags: linux, command-line, usb, cache, unmounting

## Abstract

Sometimes, the Linux kernel is not aware of on-drive write caches of external USB storage devices. Is it necessary in such situations to explicitly flush those caches prior detaching these devices?

## Example

I use a WD Elements external USB HDD of which `hdparm -I` says

```
...
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       ...
       *    Write cache
...
```

and `hdparm -W`:

```
...
 write-caching =  1 (on)
```

On the other hand, when I plug in the drive, I get the following kernel messages for it:

```
... No Caching mode page found
... Assuming drive cache: write through
```

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30634/320385) by Kyle Jones, these kernel messages indicate that the kernel assumes that its write operations will go directly to the platter.

The section "write_cache (RW)" of the file [Documentation/block/queue-sysfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/queue-sysfs.txt) in the Linux Kernel Documentation describes an implication of the kernel assuming a write through cache mode (thanks to [Wayne Conrad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294525/320385)):

> ... "write through", ... will also eliminate cache flushes issued by
>   the kernel.

## Questions

Up to now, my standard method to detach external USB storage devices from a Linux system was to unmount all mounted partitions on it, to wait until the drive's LED stops flashing, to physically unplug the USB connector, and if this does not power down the device (some have a separate power supply), to explicitly power it down.

**Is this method safe, or does it imply the risk of loosing unflushed data in the on-drive write cache, in particular if the kernel is unaware of that cache?**

In the latter case, it seems to be advisable to explicitly flush the on-drive write cache after the unmount by sending an SCSI sync command. This can be done for example using `sg_sync` which comes with the sg3-utils:

```
sg_sync <device>
```

**Would this solve the problem? Or should this be supplemented by an SCSI stop command to the device?**

The latter could be issued with (again sg3-utils):

```
sg_start 0 -r <device>
```

**Are `sg_sync` and `sg_start` the right tools for this purpose or is it better to use one of the tools and methods that I mention below in section "Related methods" or to do something else to handle the problem?**

To point out the relevance of this question, see [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178638/eject-safely-remove-vs-umount#comment444257_178650) by ack.

Please note: I am not looking for a method to primarily spin down or power off a HDD by software—unplugging the drive and using power switches have proven to be rather reliable in this respect. Instead, I am looking for a method that guarantees that all written data have made it to a non-volatile storage prior the drive is shut down, including data that was cached on-drive.

## Related methods

In the following, I give some comments on methods that I found to be related to flushing on-drive caches or, more general, to "safe removal" of removable storage devices. There, one aspect is the availability of the involved tools on existing Linux systems. This matters because it is not always possible to simply install missing software.

**Desktop environment:** Some desktop environments offer widgets to "safely remove" external USB storage devices. See for example these questions:

- "[Eject / safely remove vs umount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178638/320385)" by LGenzelis,
- "[How works the "eject usb driver" from Gnome?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421692/320385)" by k.Cyborg.

and related posts.

Depending on the implementation, these widgets seem to power down the devices, but I did not find any reference that clarifies whether they cause the devices to flush their caches beforehand, especially in cases in which the kernel is not aware of external on-drive caches.

In addition, many Linux systems (for example pure servers) do not have any desktop environment installed. So this method is not always available.

**udisks:** According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178648/320385) by jimmij, [`udisks` by Freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks) can be used from the command line to "safely remove" an external USB storage device:

```
udisks --unmount /dev/sda1
udisks --detach /dev/sda
```

This [excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129282/320385) by Totor describes what the `udisks --detach` command does:

> - sends SCSI sync-cache command,
> - sends SCSI stop command,
> - unbinds the usb-storage kernel driver,
> - suspends the USB device (power),
> - logically disables/removes it from its USB port.

So it explicitly takes care of the on-drive caches. However, `udisks` is only available on about one half of the Linux systems I have to deal with.

**udisksctl:** Recent versions of udisks provide for the program `udisksctl`, that can be used for a substitute of the `udisks` commands shown above. This is again according to [jimmij's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178648/320385):

```
udisksctl unmount -b <partition>
udisksctl power-off -b <device>
```

The same answer also cites the description of the `power-off` command in the [udisksctl(1) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/udisksctl.1.html):

> power-off
>
> Arranges for the drive to be safely removed and powered off. On the OS
>   side this includes ensuring that no process is using the drive, then
>   requesting that in-flight buffers and caches are committed to stable
>   storage.

Unfortunately this does not specify whether the "in-flight buffers and caches" includes external on-drive caches that the kernel is not aware of. But it is likely that `udisksctl` follows its predecessor `udisks` in this respect.

Unfortunately, `udisksctl` definitely does follow its predecessor with respect to its rather low availability on existing systems (compared to the availability of `umount`, for example).

**eject:** According to [its man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eject.1.html), the command line tool `eject` can be used to eject removable media under software control. Affected partitions will be unmounted beforehand as needed.

Albeit this tool shows up in several discussions on "safe removal" of removable media, see for example [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178638/320385) by LGenzelis and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421692) by k.Cyborg, nothing indicates that it does more than an unmount in this respect.

In addition, I suspect that this tool focuses more on media and media trays than on devices. This might be the reason why it simply dies with the error message

```
eject: unable to eject
```

when it is applied on the WD Elements USB drive that I mentioned as the introductory example above. However, it succeeds on some USB memory sticks.

Nevertheless, as a part of the linux-utils, this tool is highly available.

**sg3-utils:** The programs `sg_sync` and `sg_start` were already discussed above.

[This comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/466575/comments/30) by quirks to an Ubuntu bug report indicates that `udisks` internally uses the sg3-utils to send its SCSI sync and stop commands to the device.

It seems to me that the sg3-utils have a wider availability than udisks. But this is only a vague and personal impression.

**sdparm:** [This web page](http://elliotli.blogspot.com/2009/01/safely-remove-usb-hard-drive-in-linux.html) by Yan Li discusses a procedure to "Safely remove an USB hard drive in Linux". For that purpose, it recommends [a script](http://github.com/mlogic/suspend-usb-device) that in principle uses the following `sdparm` commands to flush on-drive caches and to stop (spin down?) the USB HDD:

```
sdparm --command=sync <device>
sdparm --command=stop <device>
```

These seem to be comparable to the `sg_sync` and `sg_start` commands discussed above, and might be used as a substitute for the latter.

**hdparm:** Being basically a tool to manage ATA drives, `hdparm` is in some sense a foreign object when it comes to USB drives, because the latter are primarily addressed as SCSI devices in Linux. In cases like our WD Elements example, there is an ATA HDD sitting behind an SCSI to ATA translation layer (SAT layer). See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106020) by Mikko Rantalainen for more details. Depending on the SAT's implementation, `hdparm` can be used with limited functionality to manipulate these drives.

If supported, one can use the commands

```
hdparm -F <device>
hdparm -Y <device>
```

to flush the on-drive caches and to stop the drives. If this is not possible, one might think of using

```
hdparm -W0 <device>
```

as a workaround to flush the caches. But beware: This command is actually intended to switch the on-drive write caching off. Therefore one should make sure that it actually flushes rather than simply drops the cache contents that was accumulated up to now.

For the WD Elements drive, none of these commands work: Instead they report `bad/missing sense data`.

**sysfs:** Scattered over the web, there are recipes to unbind an external USB drive from its driver, to unregister the drive from the system, or to power it down by manipulating device attributes that the Linux kernel exposes in its sysfs.

Here is an example from [this post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=311645&sid=ad0eb02dc0599385457ed6622a147ab1#p311645) by bash in the Debian forum:

```
echo "auto" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-5/power/level"
echo "1-5:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-5\:1.0/driver/unbind
```

and

```
echo "1" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-5/remove"
```

Or from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384075) by Tony George:

```
echo 'offline' > /sys/block/sdb/device/state
echo '1' > /sys/block/sdb/device/delete
```

I have too little knowledge about the concepts that the kernel developers had in mind regarding the usage of these attributes to be able to judge these code snippets. But I have some doubt that they are helpful to flush on-drive write caches that the kernel is not aware of.

In addition, it seems that at least some of these recipes are outdated. In this respect, see the first paragraph of the "[Sysfs Rules](https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/master/Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt)" in the kernel documentation as of 2019-01-25:

> The kernel-exported sysfs exports internal kernel implementation
>   details  and depends on internal kernel structures and layout. It is
>   agreed upon by the kernel developers that the Linux kernel does not
>   provide a stable internal API. Therefore, there are aspects of the
>   sysfs interface that may not be stable across kernel releases.

**Umount and wait:** This is the method that I referred to in my question above: It comprises an unmount and a subsequent waiting until the (presumably) write activities on the drive have finally ceased. The next and final step is to hope that the on-drive write caches were flushed in the course of that.

It is the main point of this question to clarify whether this is a safe method (for the data).

In any case, this method has the big advantage that it is easy, it is available on any Linux system I know, and the syntax of the `umount` command did not change over decades.

## Further reading

Some general discussions about "ejecting" and "safe removal" of USB or other external storage devices can be found in the context of these questions:

- "[Safest way to remove USB drive on Linux [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/354138/320385)" by Pkkm,
- "[Eject USB drives / eject command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35508)" by Joe Barr,
- "[When is it safe to disconnect my external HDD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70635/320385)" by jcora.

In addition, Luis Alvarado describes in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/210556) the differences between the options "Unmount", "Eject", and "Safely Remove Drive" that are offered by Ubuntu's desktop environment, in particular that there is more to "Safely Remove Drive" than just an unmount. With respect to the latter see also

- [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421692) by k.Cyborg,
- [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421711) to it by Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy,
- [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178638/320385) by LGenzelis,
- [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354138/safest-way-to-remove-usb-drive-on-linux#comment627777_354138) by Tim Kennedy.

Many contributions take the view that it is "safe to remove" an external storage device as soon as it is unmounted. Here some examples:

- [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70637/320385) by Patrick,
- [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70638/320385) by depquid,
- [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35509) by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams,
- [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354138/safest-way-to-remove-usb-drive-on-linux#comment627432_354138) by xhienne.

Some contributions focus on spinning down external HDDs in addition to an unmount. See for example [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/56270) by winchendonsprings. In [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354138/safest-way-to-remove-usb-drive-on-linux#comment627638_354175), sourcejedi points out that spinning down an USB drive reduces its vulnerability to mechanical disturbances.

Others aim on powering off USB drives:

- [This post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=311645&sid=ad0eb02dc0599385457ed6622a147ab1#p311645) by bash,
- [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384075) by Tony George.

In the following contributions, on-drive caches are explicitly mentioned with respect to "safe removal" of storage devices:

- [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98628/320385) by Michael Hamilton,
- [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129282/320385) by Totor,
- [this web page](http://elliotli.blogspot.com/2009/01/safely-remove-usb-hard-drive-in-linux.html) by Yan Li,
- [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178638/eject-safely-remove-vs-umount#comment444257_178650) by ack.

The latter is the only contribution I have found that points out the damage that can arise due to wrong assumptions of the kernel with respect to external on-drive write caching. This is exactly the focus of this question. According to that comment, simply unmounting the drive is not enough to prevent that damage. Further details and possible ways to do it right would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you should at least do a bit of research before asking! ... I'm obviously joking : fantastic research. +1

Comment: Unmounting includes a prior sync command, which includes flushing the buffers of the OS + instructing the device to force any cache to permanent storage. For remote devices on a slow connection, this can take many minutes. If the device has an onboard write cache, it doesn't help the kernel to know about it, since it isn't independently accessible.

Comment: Its known that commodity drives mis-report storage commits (thought to be deliberate to make the benchmakrs look better). If the disk is lying, then nothing you do in the OS can be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a great and well-written question.  Huge thumbs up to the OP!  Unfortunately, I can't upvote the question because I don't have enough points.

Here's a brief summary of how microSD cards behave, according to the official SD standards that I've been going through.  Of course, that doesn't apply to USB storage devices, but gives a rather good insight into the underlying issues.

In a nutshell, a microSD card can be told to prepare itself for removal, but it can still have some "invisible" internal write cache that may not be completely flushed even after the card responds with an OK to the "prepare yourself for removal" command.  The SD standard leaves such behavior to the discretion of a card's manufacturer.  As a result, in general, microSD cards should be given some rather unspecified amount of time before removal, to get their "invisible" write caches flushed.  That boils down to wating for 20 seconds or so.

Another example is what Intel says officially about some of its enterprise SSDs in form of PCI Express expansion cards:  Don't turn the system back on for about half a minute (or a minute, I forgot the exact amount of time) after powering it down.  The SSD may probably perform some internal maintenance on its own, using the on-board capacitors as the power source, which must not be interrupted by the host system powering on and asking the SSD to do something.

With all that in mind, I'd say that it's the best to just wait for some time before unplugging a USB storage device, after running `umount(8)` and `eject(1)` on it.  That's how I do it, although running just `eject(1)` is enough.  See, even if you were able to find an official low-level explanation of how flushing the write cache, visible or invisible, works on a particular USB storage device, another USB storage device would almost surely behave internally in an at least slightly different way, making it all not generally usable.

As a note, you can run `eject -v` to see what it actually does.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bigger issue and there have been solutions. The database which is executing faster due to these disk write caches is not in control of when they disappear in an uncoordinated way, that is the kernel: in typical systems the database is not in the loop when the disk write cache is lost, due to critical events.

Database systems have attempted a solution to this gap of responsibility versus control on open systems via implementing a handler on NMI, the non-maskable interrupt that executes when most if not all of these events occur (panic, machine check, bios freakouts, etc.). Not handling 100% of failures, something less than that: never let the perfect be the enemy of the good.

This handler would first execute a flush on all disk caches, and then after a settling time send an "I'm Dying" message via a local multicast to the partner nodes in the cluster, to rid us of the multi-second timeouts on those systems that have to regroup the consensus on whether that node is really up or not (their death message can be made absolutely trustworthy by encryption). You would still need heartbeats, for when the multicast message got trapped on a network failure.

The upshot of this is that distributed recovery from the loss of this node in the cluster can take effect (most of the time) in small numbers of milliseconds, and the disks on that node have less to do in terms of recovering from loss of disk caches.

Time matters.

```
       Availability = MTBF/(MTBF + MTTR)
```

[MTBF == mean time before failure, MTTR == mean time to repair.]

As MTTR approaches zero, availability approaches 1, setting aside all of the myriad potential sources of failure: so MTTR is the thing to work on first and foremost.

Of course, if your database has excellent log recovery (like free PostgreSQL and others) and is not just depending on backups and thus never consistently recovered with the database state at the time of the failure, then you can give yourself ultra low MTTR and ultra high availability for a crash consistent database.

Answer (score -1):

I have been scouring the internet for answers on an boot error about write cache on external drives connected via usb. To answer the first question
a) yes it is important to flush the buffers/cache before pulling out the usb. I suggest that like it or not, you need to umount the external usb drive so that the os can ensure that everything is written out to the hard drive.
b) reading everything that i have read, and figuring out that the answer was just in front of me. "I believe the error about cache page code not found, assuming write through" (found while using the journalctl -b command), is inherent with booting the system with an external hard drive attached via usb. This is a matter of good design!!! USB devices can be pulled out at any time. If they are without the os aware or given enough time to prepare, the data becomes corrupted!!! So the errors that are recorded by the journalctl, will be ignored by me because it is part of the design. The only way for me to avoid those errors would be not to mount them via the /etc/fstab and let it automount, when plugged in.

Comment: I believe the author of the question is trying to ask how to ensure that the cache memory of the USB attached drive is itself written to the the drive _after_ unmounting but before pulling power; this answer doesn't address that question.

Comment: I'd assume issuing command `sync` should solve such problems..